# WIX 3.x: How can I set a property from a powershell customaction ?

Tags: powershell, wix, windows-installer

I'm fairly new to wix and powerscript and I'm having trouble figuring out how to set a property from a customaction powershell script.

I cannot do manual/hand tweaking of the tables

I've been using this as a guide: [How do I populate a ComboBox at install time in WiX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373600/how-do-i-populate-a-combobox-at-install-time-in-wix)

It looks like I need to use `Session.Database.OpenView()`

I don't know how to get/use the session in powerscript.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access an MSI session from an executable like PowerShell. A DLL custom action (native or managed) can.

Comment: Hi Bob, sorry for being dense. Can you explain why it works with Jscript and vbscipt ?  Do I need to push a demand for the "scripting stone" up the hill ?  I've been looking in the M$ docs and can't seem to track down why the other scripts have access to the session object. If you have pointer, it would be appreciated.

Comment: I found it in the "small print" The installer has it's own script motor running in the installer's context. Powershell and other called processes are separate from the installer's scope. It looks like time for a talk with Hades about that stone.