# Why in Wix is iis:WebAddress Port needed?

Tags: iis, wix, installation, windows-installer

Why in Wix is iis:WebAddress Port needed if you can and do set the port for the 'website' in IIS?

I have tried and making them different. The install does not fail, but uses the port for the website. Seems odd?

Code snippet

```
  <Component Id="DataAccessorService_VirtualDir" Guid="*">
    <CreateFolder />
    <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="DataAccessorService_VirtualDir" 
                       Alias="DataAccessorService" 
                       Directory="DataAccessorServiceDir" 
                       WebSite="XCBServiceWebsite">
      <iis:WebApplication Id="DataAccessorService_VirtualDir" 
                          Name="DataAccessorService" Isolation="medium" />
      <iis:WebDirProperties Id="DataAccessorService_WebDirProperties" 
                            DefaultDocuments="DataAccessor.svc" />
    </iis:WebVirtualDir>
  </Component>
```

...

```
<iis:WebSite Id="XCBServiceWebsite" Description="BankDotNet">
  <iis:WebAddress Id="AllUnassigned" Port="85" />
</iis:WebSite>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure? I failed to find the Port attribute of WebSite element... What version of WiX are you using? A code snippet will add value as well...

Comment: I've added an example.. think it is 3.5 I am using....

Comment: So... you specify the Port attribute only once, in WebAddress element... what's your question about then? :)

Comment: That it is meaningless.. you also specify a port in IIS.. and that seems to be king. Whatever I set the port to in WebAdress is ignored.

Comment: My suspicion is that the IIS WiX extension uses that to configure the local Firewall.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. You might find this thread useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346852/in-wix-how-can-i-select-an-iis-website-by-name. Be sure to check the accepted answer and the wix-users post it references

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For WiX v2.0 and WiX v3.0 the WebAddress is how the web site in IIS is detected. The IP:Port:Header tuple is the only thing that must be unique in IIS6 that is why it was used for detection. In that tuple, the Port was the only thing that is not optional.

In WiX v3.5+ I think the WiX IIS custom action was enhanced to handle finding web sites using the Description and SiteId.