# Finding or creating web application using WiX

Tags: iis, wix, wix3.7

I have this requirement where I have to install files to a web application that may or may not exist, in an existing web site. I was hoping to convert our current custom actions to use the iis extension.

Basically, what I have right now is a dialog that contain a combobox listing all available websites and a button to load a second combobox with all of the site's web applications. The user can either select one or enter a name for a new application.

On clicking next, if the web application doesn't exist, the user is presented with a dialog to select the application pool and an installation folder, else the setup skips that dialog. The web application is then created through a custom action that is launched upon clicking install.

I've read through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346852/in-wix-how-can-i-select-an-iis-website-by-name), which gave me quite a bit of insight on how the iis extension works, but it still doesn't quite answer my questions.

If I put a web application element in a component and the application already exists, does it use that one, overwrite it or create a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will overwrite the web application. This is usually desired so that you know that your web application is configured the way you need it configured.